# Скрыть метод в наследуемом классе

Tags: c++, ооп, классы

Есть необходимость переопределить видимость метода наследуемого от базового, или запретить его переопределение.

Я пробовал переопределить так:

```
class some_super_class
{
...
protected:
    virtual void some_protected_method();
...
}
```

```
class some_child_class : protected some_super_class
{
private:
    some_super_class::some_protected_method();
}
```

Но по каким то причинам таким образом я не могу получать доступ к методам, членам класса находящимся внутри класса `some_child_class` только внутри метода `some_protected_method();`.

Как правильно переопределить видимость у наследуемого объекта?

Comment: Вы пытаетесь обмануть или нарушить основные принципы ООП. Скрывать можно сверху-вниз а не снизувверх. С какой целью? Всеравно если метод в классе верхнего уровня доступен - вы на доступ к нему повлиять не сможете. Если ваша цель - **скрыть реализацию **- собирайте dll, запутывайте - и отдавайте заказчику dll + lib. Если вы хотите реально ограничить доступность метода - анализируйте стек вызова, и вызывайте исключение либо делайтё возврат ошибки, если в вызове есть/нету звеньев, которые вы считаете нужными.

Comment: @nick_n_a: Цель не скрыть реализацию, а скрыть метод, дабы его нельзя было переопределить, т.к. из него будут вызываться виртуальные методы без которых объект просто не сможет ничего сделать.

Comment: Есть некий интерфейс, который вы наследуете, вопрос этот интерфейс пользователю наверху нужен? Если нет - обьявляйте приватный интерфейс - и пользователь не сможет его переопределить.

Comment: В других языках есть указание `sealed` или `final` возможно http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712992/how-to-define-sealed-class-in-c это поможет. Исскуственно можно, но прийдётся много методов-"обвёрток" писать.

Comment: Или так `class some_child_class : private some_super_class` или возможно так  `class some_child_class {  private:class  over1: public some_super_class {/*Обвертка, если нужно разширить суперкласс, скрытая часть*/} ; private:over1    secretInstance;  public void method1(){/*обвертка метода*/  secretInstance.method1(); } `

Comment: Скрыть метод - безсмысленно (нарушение ООП), если "защитить от переопределения", то можно. Подключить родительский класс так, что б он не наследовался - тоже можно. Отредактируйте вопрос.

Comment: просто не делайте функцию виртуальной

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для того, чтобы запретить переопределение виртуальной функции в производном классе можно использовать контекстно-зависимое слово `final`:

```
struct B {
    virtual void f() final;
};

struct D : B {
    void f() override; // Ошибка из-за попытки переопределения final функции
};
```

Видимость функции тоже можно поменять в производном классе, однако из-за виртуальности функций к ней всё равно можно будет обратиться через указатель/ссылку на базовый класс:

```
struct B {
    virtual void f() {};
};

struct D : B {
private: // делаем приватной
    void f() override {};
};

int main()
{
    D* d = new D;
    B* b = d;

    d->f(); // ошибка из-за приватного доступа
    b->f(); // OK. Вызовется именно D::f()
}
```

Comment: Жаль конечно что нельзя переопределить область видимости, но такой вариант тоже пойдет.

Comment: @LLENN дополнил ответ про видимость.

Comment: Вот, точно, а я что-то мудрить начал с дописыванием имени базового класса. А то что доступ будет по указателю, или ссылке на базовый класс, то оно так и надо :)

Comment: решение для `с++11` (что б не писал никто *а чего не работает*)

Comment: @nick_n_a для тех, кто забыл, какой нынче год - можно дополнить :)

Comment: @nick_n_a на Мете эту [тему обсуждали](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3826/176217), кстати.